# Can't find the bug in my insertion sort program

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int i, j, key, p;
    int  A[] = {1, 3, 2, 4, 9, 8, 7};

    for (j=1; j<7; j++){

        key = A[j];

    //insert A[j] into the sorted sequence 

        i = j-1;
        while(i>0 && A[i]>key){
            A[i+1] = A[i];
            --i;
        }

        A[i+i] = key;

   }
   for(i=0; i<7; ++i){

       printf("%d ", A[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The above stated code is supposed to perform an insertion sort, however, I am getting undesirable sort with few repeated values. I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: the input is inline - the output is 2 3 3 4 4 8 8

Comment: did u step through the code with a debugger

Comment: A[i+i] = key; - looks odd maybe u mean A[i+j] = key; or A[i+1] = key;(i didnt follow the algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
A[i+i] = key;
```

should be

```
A[i+1] = key;
```

Also, you have an unused variable `p`

Comment: I don't know why this post got a down vote, but can anyone suggest if there is something wrong with it and how I can improve it?

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your Insertion Sort. The first one has pointed out by Arun A. S.

1. `A[i+1] = key;` instead of `A[i+i] = key;`
2. `while(i>=0` instead of `while(i>0`

Answer (score 1):

You need a slight modification to your code( the typo `A[i+i] = key;` was not the only problem )

```
i = j ;
while(i>0 && A[i-1]>key){
    A[i] = A[i-1];
    --i;
}  
A[i] = key;
```

I kept the condition `while(i>0` and changed the offsets, but you could keep them and change only this line `while(i>=0` instead.